# I am getting a 404 error when I try to update a resource from a Vue frontend and a Laravel backend

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

I have a Job resource that I am trying to update. My application is built with Vue on the frontend and Laravel on the backend. I am using intertia to pass data between the vue and laravel. When I try to update the Job resource I get a baffling 404 error. I have tried various ways to debug this but no luck. Here are the relevant files(web.php, JobController.php, Edit.vue):

```
//web.php
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\JobController;
use App\Http\Controllers\ProfileController;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Inertia\Inertia;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\Job;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    // return Inertia::render('Welcome', [
    //     'canLogin' => Route::has('login'),
    //     'canRegister' => Route::has('register'),
    //     'laravelVersion' => Application::VERSION,
    //     'phpVersion' => PHP_VERSION,
    // ]);
    return redirect('/jobs');
});

Route::get('/admin', function () {
    return Inertia::render('Admin');
})->middleware(['admin', 'verified'])->name('admin');;

Route::get('/dashboard', function (\Illuminate\Http\Request $request) {

    $limit = $request->get('limit', 25);
    $offset = $request->get('offset', 0);

    $query = Job::query()
            ->where('id', $request->user()->id)
            //->whereDate('created_at', '>=', Carbon::now()->subDays(30)) // Only jobs posted in the past 30 days
            ->with('tags', 'clicks')
            ->latest();

    $jobs = $query->skip($offset)->take($limit)->get();
    
    return Inertia::render('Dashboard', [
        'jobs' => $jobs
    ]);
})->middleware(['auth', 'verified'])->name('dashboard');


Route::resource('jobs', JobController::class);

Route::middleware('auth')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/profile', [ProfileController::class, 'edit'])->name('profile.edit');
    Route::patch('/profile', [ProfileController::class, 'update'])->name('profile.update');
    Route::delete('/profile', [ProfileController::class, 'destroy'])->name('profile.destroy');
});

require __DIR__.'/auth.php';

Route::get('/{job}/apply', [JobController::class, 'apply'])
    ->name('jobs.apply');

Route::get('tags', [JobController::class, 'tags'])
    ->name('jobs.tags');
```

```
<?php
\\jobcontroller.php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Job;
use App\Models\Tag;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use Inertia\Inertia;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class JobController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a job listing of the resource.
     */
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $query = Job::query()
            ->where('is_active', true)
            ->whereDate('created_at', '>=', Carbon::now()->subDays(30)) // Only jobs posted in the past 30 days
            ->with('tags')
            ->latest();

        if ($request->has('tag')) {
            $tag = $request->get('tag');
            $query->whereHas('tags', function (Builder $builder) use ($tag) {
                $builder->where('slug', $tag);
            });
        }

        //Search
        if ($request->has('s')) {
            $search = strtolower($request->get('s'));
            $query->where(function($query) use ($search) {
                $query->where('title', 'like', '%' . $search . '%')
                      ->orWhere('company', 'like', '%' . $search . '%')
                      ->orWhere('location', 'like', '%' . $search . '%');
            });
        }

        // Pagination
        $limit = $request->get('limit', 25);
        $offset = $request->get('offset', 0);
        $jobs = $query->skip($offset)->take($limit)->get();

        // Only get tags that are associated with at least one job
        //$tags = Tag::whereHas('jobs')->orderBy('name')->get();
        $tags = Tag::whereHas('jobs')->groupBy('id')->orderBy('name')->get();

        return Inertia::render('Jobs/Index', [
            'jobs' => $jobs,
            'tags'  => $tags,
        ]);
    }


    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return Inertia::render('Jobs/Create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        // process the listing creation form
        $validationArray = [
            'title' => 'required',
            'company' => 'required',
            'logo' => 'file|max:2048',
            'location' => 'required',
            'apply_link' => 'required|url',
            //'content' => 'required',
            'payment_method_id' => 'required'
        ];

        if (!Auth::check()) {
            $validationArray = array_merge($validationArray, [
                'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
                'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:5',
                'name' => 'required'
            ]);
        }

        $request->validate($validationArray);

        // is a user signed in? if not, create one and authenticate
        $user = Auth::user();

        if (!$user) {
            $user = User::create([
                'name' => $request->name,
                'email' => $request->email,
                'password' => Hash::make($request->password)
            ]);

            $user->createAsStripeCustomer();

            Auth::login($user);
        }

        // process the payment and create the listing
        try {
            $amount = 29900; // $99.00 USD in cents
            if ($request->filled('is_highlighted')) {
                $amount += 1900;
            }

            $user->charge($amount, $request->payment_method_id);

            //$md = new \ParsedownExtra();

            $job = $user->jobs()
                ->create([
                    'title' => $request->title,
                    'slug' => Str::slug($request->title) . '-' . rand(1111, 9999),
                    'company' => $request->company,
                    'logo' => basename($request->file('logo')->store('public')),
                    'location' => $request->location,
                    'apply_link' => $request->apply_link,
                    //'content' => $md->text($request->input('content')),
                    'is_highlighted' => $request->filled('is_highlighted'),
                    'is_active' => true
                ]);

            foreach(explode(',', $request->tags) as $requestTag) {
                $tag = Tag::firstOrCreate([
                    'slug' => Str::slug(trim($requestTag))
                ], [
                    'name' => ucwords(trim($requestTag))
                ]);

                $tag->jobs()->attach($job->id);
            }

            //return redirect()->route('dashboard');
            return to_route('dashboard');
        } catch(\Exception $e) {
            return redirect()->back()
                ->withErrors(['error' => $e->getMessage()]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     */
    public function show(Job $job, Request $request)
    {
        return Inertia::render('Jobs/Job', [
            'job' => $job,
            'tags' => $job->tags,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     */
    public function edit(Job $job)
    {
        return Inertia::render('Jobs/Edit', [
            'job' => $job,
            'tags' => $job->tags,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     */
    public function update(Request $request, Job $job)
    {
        $data = $request->validate([
            'title' => 'required',
            'company' => 'required',
            'location' => 'required',
            'apply_link' => 'required|url',
        ]);

        if ($request->hasFile('logo')) {
            $data['logo'] = basename($request->file('logo')->store('public'));
        }

        try {
            $job->update($data);
            return redirect()->route('dashboard');
        } catch(\Exception $e) {
            return redirect()->back()
                ->withErrors(['error' => $e->getMessage()]);
        }
    }


    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     */
    public function destroy(Job $job)
    {
        //
    }

    public function apply(Job $job, Request $request)
    {
        $job->clicks()
            ->create([
                'user_agent' => $request->userAgent(),
                'ip' => $request->ip()
            ]);

        return redirect()->to($job->apply_link);

    }

    public function tags()
    {
        $tags = Tag::all();

        return Inertia::render('Jobs/Tags', [
            'tags' => $tags,
        ]);
    }
}
```

```
//edit.vue
<template>
    <app-layout>
        <div class="container mx-auto px-4 mt-10">
            <!-- Form Section -->
            <div class="bg-gray-100 p-6 rounded-lg shadow-md">
                <div class="mb-4 pl-4 mt-4">
                    <h2 class="text-2xl font-medium text-gray-900 title-font">
                        Edit Job Listing
                    </h2>
                </div>

                <form id="edit_form" class="bg-gray-100 p-4" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <!-- Form Fields -->
                    <div class="mb-4 mx-2">
                        <label for="title" class="block font-medium text-sm text-gray-700">Job Title</label>
                        <input
                            id="title"
                            class="block mt-1 w-full"
                            type="text"
                            name="title"
                            v-model="form.title"
                            required />
                    </div>

                    <!-- Company Name -->
                    <div class="mb-4 mx-2">
                        <label for="company" class="block font-medium text-sm text-gray-700">Company Name</label>
                        <input
                            id="company"
                            class="block mt-1 w-full"
                            type="text"
                            name="company"
                            v-model="form.company"
                            required />
                    </div>

                    <!-- Company Logo -->
                    <div class="mb-4 mx-2">
                        <label for="logo" class="block font-medium text-sm text-gray-700">Company Logo</label>
                        <input
                            type="file"
                            id="logo"
                            class="mt-1 w-full"
                            ref="logoInput"
                            accept="image/*"
                            @change="onFileChange"
                        />
                        <img v-if="form.logo" :src="'/storage/' + form.logo" alt="Company Logo" class="mt-2 h-20 w-20 object-cover" />
                    </div>

                    <!-- Apply Link -->
                    <div class="mb-4 mx-2">
                        <label for="apply_link" class="block font-medium text-sm text-gray-700">Link To Apply</label>
                        <input
                            id="apply_link"
                            class="block mt-1 w-full"
                            type="text"
                            name="apply_link"
                            v-model="form.apply_link"
                            required />
                    </div>

                    <!-- Job Tags -->
                    <div class="mb-4 mx-2">
                        <label for="tags" class="block font-medium text-sm text-gray-700">Tags (separate by comma)</label>
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            id="tags"
                            class="block mt-1 w-full"
                            v-model="tagsInput"
                            placeholder="Enter tags separated by commas"
                        />
                    </div>

                    <!-- Job Location -->
                    <div class="mb-4 mx-2">
                        <label for="location" class="block font-medium text-sm text-gray-700">Location</label>
                        <input
                            id="location"
                            class="block mt-1 w-full"
                            type="text"
                            name="location"
                            v-model="form.location"
                            required />
                    </div>


                    <!-- Submit Button -->
                    <div class="flex justify-end mt-4">
                        <button type="submit" @click="submitForm($event)" class="bg-indigo-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded">
                            Update Listing
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </app-layout>
</template>

<script setup>
import AppLayout from '../../Components/AppLayout.vue';
import { usePage, useForm } from '@inertiajs/vue3'
import { ref, toRefs, watchEffect } from 'vue';

const page = usePage();

const form = useForm({
    title: page.props.job.title,
    company: page.props.job.company,
    logo: page.props.job.logo,
    apply_link: page.props.job.apply_link,
    tags: page.props.job.tags.map(tag => tag.name),
    location: page.props.job.location,
});


// methods
const onFileChange = (e) => {
    let files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;
    if (!files.length)
        return;
    form.logo = files[0];
};

const submitForm = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    form.put(route('jobs.update', page.props.job.id), { onError: () => console.log(form.errors) });
};

const tagsInput = ref(form.tags.join(', '));

watchEffect(() => {
    form.tags = tagsInput.value.split(',').map(tag => tag.trim());
});
</script>
```

Please note that when I run `php artisan route:list` I get the expected route for the update method:

```
PUT|PATCH       jobs/{job} ................................... jobs.update › JobController@update
```

Comment: Often most important is the concrete URL of the request and it's method. That's how Vue "talks" to Laravel and if Laravel has no route, then 404. However that does not tell you if the route is missing or the URL was wrong. Check the request speaks the right language before pulling all of the code apart.

Comment: Could you elaborate on your comment? Do you mean setting request type to `application/json`?

Comment: Not sure it's that `application/json` (you mean content-type?), for routing - and that's also in Laravel routing - the first key part is the path component in the URL. Then the method (GET, PUT, POST - you know it) and then perhaps content-type negotiation, but I'm not that much into that part w/ Laravel, it's perhaps a detail and likely will give a different repsonse code than 404. IIRC 404 is most often the path component of the URL.